# How to connect to cassandra from outside the cluster

Tags: cassandra, server, connection, client, datastax

I am currently learning Cassandra using datastax tutorials and other online resources. I got the main concepts and feature of it, but I miss one crucial thing of the whole picture, which is how to connect to Cassandra from outside the cluster.

More in detail, the information I cannot find is whether Cassandra needs a node of the cluster to act as a sever for incoming requests and to dispatch them to the other ones, or if it comes with an embedded mechanism to balance them in the cluster. Any kind of information (from low-level to advanced) is welcome.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically one would connect using one of the native protocol [client drivers](http://www.planetcassandra.org/apache-cassandra-client-drivers/). The drivers take as configuration one or more server nodes as "contact points". They connect to one of these nodes and read server metadata to "discover" the rest of the cluster.

While any node in the cluster can act as a request coordinator, drivers also use some type of load balancing to spread traffic over the cluster, and routing to send requests to nodes that actually have replicas (avoiding unnecessary hops).

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. I thought the client drivers were all I need since there wasn't really anything else mentioned, but since I did not find any resource explicitly saying it, I was in confusion. One last follow-up question: how do the list of nodes that I provide to the driver influences the Cluster? Should I try to keep it as much complete as possible or not?

Comment: @riccamini  Don't worry about keeping that list up-to-date.  The drivers really just use that list for the initial connection, and then they gossip with the other nodes in the cluster to figure out where to send your request.  So it will still send requests to a new node, regardless of whether or not it is listed in your contact points or not.

Comment: +1; It really comes down to having enough contact points so that at least one (not ignored in the load balancing policy) is available to connect when you start the session. The rest are discovered and updated dynamically.